# Google Cloud Bigtable fails to list tables

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

In Google Cloud Bigtable using Quickstart, I tried to create a table then executed "List" which results in an error message below and termination of the HBase shell.  Please advise...thanks.

```
hbase(main):003:0> list
TABLE
Exception `NativeException' at /home/chopehill/quickstart/thirdparty/ruby/hbase/admin.rb:48 - java
.io.IOException: Failed to listTables
ERROR: NOT_FOUND: Error listing tables for cluster projects/foodie-1300/zones/us-central1-b/cluste
rs/quickstart-cluster : Failed to read Tables in cluster: quickstart-cluster
Here is some help for this command:
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:
  hbase> list
  hbase> list 'abc.*'
  hbase> list 'ns:abc.*'
  hbase> list 'ns:.*'
hbase(main):004:0> May 03, 2016 6:07:46 AM com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.Transpo
rtSet$TransportListener transportShutdown
INFO: Transport com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@12679545(bigtabl
etableadmin.googleapis.com/173.194.74.219:443) for bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com/173.194.74.21
9:443 is being shutdown
May 03, 2016 6:07:46 AM com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.TransportSet$TransportList
ener transportTerminated
INFO: Transport com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@12679545(bigtabl
etableadmin.googleapis.com/173.194.74.219:443) for bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com/173.194.74.21
9:443 is terminated
```

Comment: I think you mean "BigTable", not "BigQuery" right?

Comment: Is this in cloud shell?

Comment: NOT_FOUND indicates that the configuration your provided (foodie-1300, us-central1-b, quickstart-cluster) does not exist.

Comment: I've updated the quickstart to not require JAVA_HOME to be set.  If you have only one Bigtable cluster, then just do: cd quickstart; chmod +x quickstart.sh; ./quickstart.sh

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the **NOT_FOUND** error indicates that the cluster you attempted to query did not exist. This may be due to an issue with how you set up your cluster prior to using the `quickstart.sh` script.